# Speeding Up an Inefficient Python Loop - For loop with data frames

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, optimization

I do not have any formal software training and I am working on a personal project that I'm hoping to get some help with. I have managed to get everything working, but one part of my program is terribly inefficient and causes the whole thing to take 2 days to execute.

Essentially what I have is a long list of strings. Each element can be one of a few different strings (call them 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D'). Along with this there are two data frames. The first contains start and end values, while the second keeps track of the number of times each string in the list occurs between the start and end values.

Here is the code I have that works, but is very slow:

Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the test list
test_list = []
for i in range(0, 250):
    test_list.append('A')
    test_list.append('B')
    test_list.append('C')
    test_list.append('D')

# Create the test dataframes
data_1 = []
columns_1 = ['start', 'end']
for i in range(0, 10):
    data_1.append([i, i+10])    
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns=columns_1)

data_2 = []
columns_2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
for i in range(0, 20):
    data_2.append([0, 0, 0, 0])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns=columns_2)

# The checking loop
for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
    for x in range(0, len(test_list)):
        for ind, r in df_1.iterrows():
            if r['start'] <= x <= r['end']:
                if test_list[x] == 'A':
                    df_2.at[index, 'A'] +=1
                if test_list[x] == 'B':
                    df_2.at[index, 'B'] +=1
                if test_list[x] == 'C':
                    df_2.at[index, 'C'] +=1
                if test_list[x] == 'D':
                    df_2.at[index, 'D'] +=1
```

Intuitively I can see why this is slow, but I don't have the knowledge to know what the "proper" way to structure something like this is.

Any suggestions on how I can manipulate the list and/or data frames to make this more efficient? I've monkeyed around with ProcessPoolExecutor to throw more raw power at it, but haven't been able to get that to work either.

Comment: The shown code produces the same values for each row of `df_2`, so `df_2` only needs a single row.

Comment: what do you mean by "the number of times each string in the list occurs between the start and end values." exactly? It isn't clear to me exactly what you are trying to count here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the test list
test_list = []
for i in range(0, 250):
    test_list.extend(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

# Create the test dataframes
data_1 = []
columns_1 = ['start', 'end']
for i in range(0, 10):
    data_1.append([i, i + 10])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns=columns_1)

# Create an empty DataFrame with the same structure as df_2
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df_1.index, columns=df_1.columns)

# Iterate through the test_list and update df_2 using vectorized operations
for i, row in df_1.iterrows():
    mask = (i * 40 <= np.arange(len(test_list))) & (np.arange(len(test_list)) < (i + 10) * 40)
    counts = np.array([test_list[j] for j in range(len(test_list)) if mask[j]])
    df_2.at[i, :] = [np.sum(counts == label) for label in df_2.columns]

print(df_2)
```

**Explanation**

Use test_list.extend(...) to add the elements in bulk. This reduces the number of iterations.

Create an empty DataFrame df_2 with the same structure as df_1 to store the counts.

Use NumPy arrays and boolean masking to efficiently filter the elements in test_list that fall within the specified range in df_1.

Calculate the counts for each label ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') using NumPy's vectorized operations, which are much faster than looping through each element.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I'll take a look through the concepts you've provided and see if I can make any improvements to my program.

Comment: I implemented boolean masking in my code and got the loop execution time down from ~3.3 seconds/loop to 0.003 seconds/loop! Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what your code is trying to achieve and why we end up with `df_2` that contains the same values for each of the rows.

As far as I understood it, correct me if I'm wrong, what we want is: take a value from `test_list`, check whether its index is between "start" and "end" in df_1 and then based on the value of the element record the number of times it matches.

If that's the case then it can be done very easily. First of all, if you want any kind of performance with Pandas then you should never use `iterrows()` or iterate over dataframe in any way. This is contrary to how dataframes work.

The way I'd do this:

```
res = {}

for idx, val in enumerate(test_list):
    count_matches = df_1.loc[(df_1.start < idx) & (df_1.end > idx), :].shape[0]
    try:
        res[val] += count_matches
    except KeyError:
        res[val] = count_matches
```

To get the counts we simply filter the dataframe by the value of the element's index and then take `shape[0]` which is the number of rows in the filtered df.

Here you end up with a simple dictionary that records how many times each of the elements has been encountered which, if necessary, you can easily convert to a dataframe.

Comment: My real data doesn’t have all the same values for df_2, that’s just a product of the way I built the test code.

Comment: @DanTheMan, it's impossible for me to guess what your real data would be like, isn't it? In that case, in the future I suggest supplying data that can actually reproduce the result you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

This way is fast but also easy to understand:

```
def matches_between(subset):

    result = {string: 0 for string in unique_list}
    
    for string in subset:
        result[string] += 1
    
    return result

unique_list = set(test_list)
df_1['matches'] = df_1.apply(lambda row: matches_between(test_list[row['start']:row['end']]), axis=1)
```

You then end up with a column `matches` which is a dictionary of how many times each word appeared in those indices. You can explode it out with this:

```
df_2 = df_1['matches'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
```

This code runs in 0.0009s, whereas your code runs in 2.76s even on this tiny dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It looks like this could be pointing me in the right direction, I'll see if I can get it to work for me.